# Collapse all following elements until specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, markup

I have a FAQ with jacked-up markup that looks like this:

```
<p><strong>How can I come see the animals perform?</strong><br>
Schedules and information about attending a performance can be found here:</p>
<p><a href="http://jupmingdolphins.com">Performance tickets</a></p>
<p>If no performances are listed, it means that none are scheduled in the
near future. The animals take a break between November and May.</p>

<p><strong>What's the answer to this question?</strong><br>
It's 42, of course.</p>

<h2>Header for More Questions</h2>

<p><strong>Is it true the dolphins have smartphones?</strong><br>
Yes, they use Android phones and text each other constantly.</p>
<p><b>Just kidding!</b> They are all Apple fan-fish and prefer iPhones.</p>

(etc)
```

And I'm trying to figure out:

1. Some CSS (and probably jQuery) to hide everything except the questions, on page load.
2. Simple jQuery where, when the user clicks on a `<strong>`-wrapped question, the answer slides down and appears below it. The problem is, as you can see, is that the markup is wacky (thanks to the CMS) and there can be lots of stuff between one question and another. The answers aren't wrapped in their own DIV or anything. On top of all that, there are H2 subheads throughout the FAQ, and I don't want the H2s to ever be touched/collapsed.

So I need code sort of like for the click action:

```
$('strong').click(function() {
   // hide or reveal all elements from $(this) down,
   // and stop when we hit next <strong> or <h2>
});
```

Comment: Why not a *definition list*?

Comment: Can the source of the markup change? To achieve your goal, this is not the correct markup.

Comment: How long is the FAQ list? 10's, 100's, 1000's?

Comment: I agree, the markup sucks terribly, but it's what I have to work with. The FAQ is about 40 questions. The markup is generated by the CMS so I can't even really clean it up by hand.

Comment: So we need to assume that a question will always be in a `strong` tag and that any following `p` belong the the first `p`+`strong` until either the next `p`+`strong` or a `h2` (two ending conditions).  If there are multiple `strong` tags, this could confuse things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

This is greatly complicated by the fact that the questions don't even have their own tags.  So you're in the awkward spot of needing to hide a question's parent tag, but show the question itself, which is basically impossible.

To get around this problem, [here is a hack](http://jsfiddle.net/AvpM9/7/) I put together.  It clones the questions and appends them in their own tag.  But, I'd recommend trying to prevail on the authors of this markup to revise it into something more rational.

---

To hide the non-questions, it looks like you could use something like:

```
$("#container").children().not($("strong").parent()).not("p").hide();
```

To show an answer, you could probably use [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$(this).parent().nextUntil($("strong").parent()).show();
```

---

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AvpM9/7/)**

Comment: You need to target `p` tags (easy to do) so that any `h2`'s are unaffected.

Comment: @MarcAudet you're right ... it's hard to give a complete answer to the question, as it looks incomplete.  (what other markup patterns does the Op have to deal with?)

Comment: The jQuery seems to work pretty well.  Clever trick to hide all the `p`'s first and then grab the heading.  Nice!

Comment: So good, I wish I could mark it correct twice. Thanks for helping me wrangle this awful markup!